# Cannot get custom category attribute value on the category page issue

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I made this code to create the custom attribute:

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    Category::ENTITY,
    'is_tile',
    [
        'type'         => 'int',
        'label'        => 'My Custom Label',
        'input'        => 'boolean',
        'sort_order'   => 100,
        'source'       => '',
        'global'       => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'      => true,
        'required'     => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default'      => null,
        'group'        => '',
        'backend'      => '',
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true
    ]
);

$this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
```

It works, I can save the value of **is_tile** on the backend side. But I would like to get it in this phtml file:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
```

**products.phtml:**

```
<?php $category = $block->getCurrentCategory(); ?>
<?php var_dump($category->getData('is_tile')); ?>
```

But the output of my `var_dump` is `NULL` .
I've also made this file in my module etc/catalog_attributes.xml, with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="is_tile"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

But I am still getting the `null` value. How can I get my custom category attribute value, without reloading the category?  like here:

```
$categoryId = 5;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($object_manager->getData('is_tile'));
```

Comment: In your examples you have a typo - instead of is_title you have is_tile

Comment: @paj good catch , but I still have this issue.  I updated my post.

Comment: have u did indexing

Comment: Hey @AmitBera Yes, I did, but still the same :). If I use the object manager to reload the category, it works . But as I said ,  I would like to avoid this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  below solution:

```
  $resource = $category->getResource();
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
    $ressource->getAttributeRawValue($category->getId(),'is_tile',$store->getId())
```

here i used resource model.